# Keychain: how to set expiration time to `Internet password`?

Tags: macos, password, keychain

[image: macOS Sierra Keychain]
I see column `Expires` but how can I edit it? Attributes window does not have such field. I want that aws tool for git automatically refresh saved password that generates every 15 minutes. Or maybe I can disable caching of passwords? Or maybe in some way I can persist `always deny` for reading some passwords from Keychain? Or maybe exists some correct way to disable of using Keychain for Git? [This official article from AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-https-unixes.html) says: 'Install a version of Git that does not use the keychain by default or configure the Keychain Access utility to not provide credentials for AWS CodeCommit repositories.' How to do any of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expires is a field that Keychain uses on items which have an intrinsic expiry, such as certificates. You're not able to set passwords with an expiry.